# I have some unwanted color in my model

Tags: modeling, color

[image]

My fist atempt on creating something in blender and now there is the dark green which I cant get rif off. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What shading mode are we looking at here? Solid mode, material preview mode or render mode? In other words: which of the 4 spheres is selected at the top right of the 3D view?

Comment: Should be the third, Material Preview mode

Comment: My guess would be that we are just looking at the back of the faces that have the green color you assigned to them. Or does the object have a separate inside and outside (created with a solidify modifier, for example). If not, we might be looking at the "wrong" side of some faces (only one side of each face is meant to be seen).   Or maybe the inside is just darker because it catches less light than the outside.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean but the whole area at the front should have the light green. I used for this model two different greens, the back color is darker and is appearing at the front which it shouldnt. When I delete the darker green in the front it is also white